# Why doesn't "*pre-*relational" generate italics for "pre-"?

Tags: bug, markdown

If I write

```
*pre*relational
```

then it comes out as

> *pre*relational

with italics for the *pre* part.

If I write

```
*pre-* relational
```

then I get

> *pre-* relational

with correct italics but a space.

I would expect

```
*pre-*relational
```

to generate italics for the *pre-* part; but actually what I get is

> *pre-*relational

I can get what I'm looking for by typesetting it as

```
*pre*-relational
```

which comes out as

> *pre*-relational

because it doesn't make any difference whether the hyphen is in italics or not, but it still looks to me as though there's a bug lurking in the parsing of the `*pre-*relational` case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape the `-` by replacing it with `\-`:

Without: *pre-*relational

With: *pre-*relational

Comment: Ah, cool! Didn't know backslash operated as an escape in this context!

Answer (score 3):

It's because the "-" is inside the italic marks - as you have discovered in your testing.

From balpha's announcement here:

> [Markdown change: Intra-word emphasis now works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240354/markdown-change-intra-word-emphasis-now-works)

The following point is relevant:

> 2. If a single or double asterisk is supposed to be interpreted as intra-word emphasis, it cannot have punctuation on one side; it actually must be inside a word. An example of an edge case this solves is
>
>    > It's a web*-based solution.
>    >
>    > *see Wikipedia for a definition of "web"
>
> where the asterisks after "web" could cause unintended italicizing if there was a second asterisk in the same paragraph somewhere.

Comment: Hmm, does this mean that `*pre*-relational` shouldn't work either? (It has punctuation on one side of the second asterisk.)

Comment: @chiastic-security - Ah - it looks like the point I copied is only tangentially related to the problem. However, I would suspect that the "inside word" rule applies here too.